# Positioning a UIView between two other views. Autolayout

Tags: xcode, ios6, constraints, autolayout

I'm using Autolayout to set up quite a lot of labels and buttons in a view. One button needs to be exactly betwwen 2 UILabels and I don't know how to accomplish that. I try to get the position on one label, the position of the other, do the math, etc. But since it's using autolayout, it turns out that the frame.origin.x property is always 0.

So any clues on how to do that?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

One possible way to do this using the designer is to place a container that will fill the space between the two labels. Just drag a View onto the design surface and make sure that you have the following constraints: Top Space to the top label with default value and Bottom Space to the bottom label with default value.

Once you have this container simply place the button as a child of this container and centre the button horizontally and vertically in the container. That should do it.

[image]

This could also be done with code. Let me know if sample code is needed.